# How to implement an intellisense like amazon

Tags: jquery, search, web

I want to create a web app with an intellisense similar to the amazon technology used on the search bar to get suggestions or closed results but I didn't find anything for the web [image]. Another example is the [cocoadocs](http://cocoadocs.org/) website. With jQuery is possible to create the graphics but I need the logic or some reference to a good algorithm of creating an approximation to results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery UI has a plugin called [AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).  I suggest you start there.

You can specify a local data source (an array, basically, that's pushed to the page when you render it) for the selection data.  You can also specify an online data source, using the [source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) option.

Here's another one: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Answer (score 1):

In theory the logic is that first you have to have a **Database** that you wanna search through. then on **keydown** event of the search field, you need to use **AJAX** to connect to the DB, send the search field value and return the matched criteria using **Server Side** codes. then again in **jQuery** you need to show the respond of the Server in the pre-designed, opened box underneath the search field.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you are trying to build is called "autocomplete" or "autosuggest" , not "intellisense" ( that is Microsoft technology in its IDEs ).

There would be two parts, frontend view & backend storage to store the results.

1. Frontend : You can use your [jQuery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), or twitter [typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) for the frontend functionality.
2. Backend : This will be used to store your data, you can use anything from simple RDBMS systems like MySQL if your data search & ranking logics are not very complex. If,however you want more complex algorithms like leveinstein,ngrams ( for fuzzy string matching ), relevancy ranking, higher throughput, you would be better off using a dedicated search server like SOLR or ElasticSearch.